# How can we call setAttribute method from request object?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

SevreletRequest---extends by-->HttpSevreletRequest--implements by-->HttpServeletRequestWrapper
      None of the class or interface declare/define setAttribute method.
setAttribute method declard in jspContext interface which is extended by pageContext.
So how can we call setAttribute method through request object which is created by container and pased to service method of servlet.

Comment: Please try to use Google a bit, before posting questions, all of them (if wrote correctly) declares that method - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 1):

there is spelling mistake by you  check your spellings of ServletRequest and HttpServletRequestwrapper
and also refer to this page

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html